# Basic Authentication for All Except Listed User Agents in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4

Is it possible to require Basic Authentication for all except the specified User Agents in Apache configuration?

P.S. I know that User Agents can be easily faked, but for my use case such conditional authentication would be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching for quite a bit and experimenting, I came up with the answer. One needs these lines in their `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent ^VipAgent1 vip_agent
SetEnvIf User-Agent ^VipAgent2 vip_agent

Order Allow,Deny
Allow from env=vip_agent

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected Login"
AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
Require valid-user

Satisfy any
```

In addition, for this to work, one would need to make sure that `mod_rewrite`, `mod_authn_file`, and `mod_setenvif` are enabled in `httpd.conf` and also this directive is set there:

```
AllowOverride All
```

This configuration gives access for requests with User Agent starting "VipAgent1" and "VipAgent2", but asks for the authentication credentials for all other visitors.