# Basic Authentication for All Except Listed User Agents in nginx

Tags: nginx

I've written [an analogous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/865174/basic-authentication-for-all-except-listed-user-agents-in-apache) about Apache configuration, but I'm also interested in nginx.

Is it possible to require Basic Authentication for all except specified User Agents in nginx configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After several evenings of research and trial and error, I found that conditional authentication can be created combining `map` directive with custom variable for `auth_basic` directive:

```
map $http_user_agent $authentication {
    default "Access Restricted";
    "~^PayPal IPN" "off";
    # ...
}

server {
    # ...
    location / {
        auth_basic $authentication;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        # ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by using nginx `map` directive.

For example:

```
map $http_user_agent $auth {
    default 0;
    "~Chrome" 1;
}

server {
    ... other vhost config ...
    if ($auth = 1) {
        auth_basic "Authenticate";
        auth_basic_user_file /path/to/authfile;
    }
}
```

The `map` directive looks into the variable specified in the first argument and declares values for the second variable based on information inside the `map` block.

Then we use the `$auth` variable to see if we want to have authentication or not.

You can read more on how to match different strings with `map` in nginx map documentation page at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

Comment: Unfortunately, auth_basic directive doesn't work inside of an if condition. Syntax error is raised. But the working solution is very similar.